# Expo / React-Native, Is it there a way to test-run standalone iOS apps on a device/simulator?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo to code my apps with React-Native. I can test my apps on Android devices running them from the Expo client app or building an APK and running it as standalone.

On iOS I can run my app from the Expo client but I couldn't find a way to run the app as standalone. In this case, I would like to test the "native" facebook login functionality.

**Is it possible to run an app as standalone (without using the Expo client) on iOS?**

Note: I'm trying to avoid going through TestFlight for this, that will make my workflow painfully slow. I am using Mac OS.

Comment: Are you using a Mac? I believe running/building it without Expo on iOS requires xCode.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a mac. Will add this to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Run `expo build:ios -t simulator` to create an iOS standalone simulator build.
2. Wait for build to finish, then download and unpack YourAppName.tar.gz
3. Start an iOS simulator and run `xcrun simctl install booted YourAppName.app`

Comment: Can you do this for an Android device?